# How to retrieve multiple attribute values from this XML file - using SimpleXML/Android

Tags: java, android, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I have tried for many hours and have gone through all possible examples on Google, but I can't figure out how to get the attributes from the  in this XML file using simplexml on Android.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Service>
<Facture FactNo="" 
 NoAppel="6" 
 ProjDate="2012-04-01"
 NomProj="MR. H. BLOOM"
 AddProj="20, GARDEN ROAD" 
 VilleProj="WESTMOUNT, QC."
 CPProj="" ContProj="M. BLOOM" 
 TelProj="(555) 555-9571" 
 SysMarque="" 
 SysMod="" 
 SysType="" 
 SysSerie="" 
 SysNo=""
 SysTemp=""
 Tension=""
 Phase="0"
 Halo="False"
 POFact=""
 NomFact=""
 AdrsFact="" 
 VilleFact=""
 CPFact=""
 TelFact=""
 FaxFact=""
 Trouble=""
 TbLock="False"
 TDesc=""
 TRec=""
 Depl="False"
 TM="False" 
 NoTM=""
 TPA="False"
 NoTPA=""
 CS="False"
 NoCS=""
 Estim="False"
 NoEstim=""
 Proj="False"
 NoProj=""
 Term="True" 
 Incompl="False"
 Garant="False"
 NoGarant=""
 Annexe="False"
 NoAnnexe=""
 NoContrat="00007"
 MainDoeuvre="0,0000" 
 Materiel="0,0000"
 SousTot=""
 TPS="0,0000"
 TPSTaux="0.05"
 TVQ="0,0000"
 TVQTaux="0.085"
 Total="0,0000" />
<Pieces>
<Piece Qty="10" Desc="test" PO="12345678" PrixUnit="0.0000" Montant="0.0000" />
<Piece Qty="25" Desc="testitem2" PO="33333" PrixUnit="22.0000" Montant="220.0000"            />
<Piece Qty="35" Desc="testitem3" PO="44444" PrixUnit="33.0000" Montant="440.0000"     />
</Pieces>
<Techs>
<Tech Nom="Bobby" Reg="1" TD="2" Taux="3.5000" Montant="0.0000" Lock="False" Date="2012-04-01   
10:49:00" />
</Techs>
<Sign />
<Pics />
</Service>
```

The XML file is third party so I cannot modify it.

Class for Service (only showing for Piece):

```
    //Liste Pieces
    @ElementList(name="Piece", inline=true)
    @Path("Pieces")
    private List<PieceXML> pieces;

    public List<PieceXML> getpieces()
    {
        return pieces;
    }
```

Class for Piece:

```
@Root(name="Piece")
public class PieceXML 
{

@Attribute
private Double Qty;
@Attribute
private String Desc;
@Attribute
private String PO;
@Attribute
private Double PrixUnit;
@Attribute
private Double Montant;
 ...}
```

What I actually need is to build an array from the attribute values in Piece, but really can't figure out how to do it.  Any help would be very appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK finally got it working by myself.  Figures out it was pretty straight-forward.  I had it all the way but could not get it working because I had issues with nodes that were named exactly like existing classes of my application which resulted in getting null values when reading my returned list of objects.  In that case I had to use the

```
@Path(pathname)
```

call with complete path i.e.

```
@Path("Service/Pieces").
```

I could then get my

```
List<PieceXML>
```

Object and fill my ArrayLists.

Comment: ElementList and type are what might help you